# Decreasing Counter not Working

Tags: c#, image, grid

I am trying to make a counter using an array that I used when I created several images, after a certain amount of time the image should disappear if it is not clicked, I am new to C#, and I am very confused. I think I have it for the most part, but it does not seem to work, thanks. In the code I include the two methods that use this array, CreateImage() which creates the "Mole" image, then adds it to a random spot on the grid, and deleteMole() where I am trying to delete this mole after 4 seconds.

Code:

```
private void ChangeImage()
{
    string Moleimage = TUtils.GetIniFileString(Moleini, "ImagePath", "PictureFile", Root + "mole2.png");
    NumofImages = TUtils.GetIniInt(Moleini, "NumPictures", "pictures", 8);
    String MoleImageFunction = TUtils.GetIniFileString(Moleini, "ImagePath", "PictureFile", Root + "mole2.png");

    for (int j = 0; j > NumofImages; j++)
    {
        ListArray[j]++;
    }
    Image newImage = HoleImage();

    molePopup = MoleImage();

    int numCol = Convert.ToInt32(NumberOfColumns);

    int ranCol = randomColumns.Next(1, numCol);

    int ranRow = randomRow.Next(1, NumberofRows);


    Image mole = new Image();
    //for (int i = 0; i < NumofImages; i++)
    //{

    mole.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(MoleImageFunction));
    mole.Name = "Mole" + ListArray;
    mole.Width = ImageSize;
    mole.Height = ImageHeight;
    //}

    Grid.SetColumn(mole, ranCol);
    Grid.SetRow(mole, ranRow);
    grid_Main.Children.Add(mole);

    //Calling MoileLifeCounter for Mole Death
    moleLifeCounter();

    mole.MouseUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler((o, e) =>
    {
        grid_Main.Children.Remove(mole);
        MolePoints++;
    });
}

private void deleteMole()
{
    NumofImages = TUtils.GetIniInt(Moleini, "NumPictures", "pictures", 8);
    int NumberofImages;
    NumberofImages = Convert.ToInt32(NumofImages);

    for (int j  = 0; j > NumofImages; j++)
    {
        ListArray[j]--;

        if (ListArray[j] == 0)
        {
            int numCol = Convert.ToInt32(NumberOfColumns);

            int ranCol = randomColumns.Next(1, numCol);

            int ranRow = randomRow.Next(1, NumberofRows);

            Image newImage = HoleImage();

            Grid.SetColumn(HoleImage(), ranCol);
            Grid.SetRow(HoleImage(), ranRow);
            grid_Main.Children.Add(HoleImage());

            Console.WriteLine("TIMER WORKED!");
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `ListArray` declared?

Comment: Does it give any indication on what the problem might be?

Comment: @emd I am declaring ListArray in the globals " uint[] ListArray; "

Comment: @AdamSweeney Does what give any indication?

Comment: When your program runs, does it throw an exception or anything...or does it just not work at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks to me like the loop which decrements the counter is never entered

```
for (int j  = 0; j > NumofImages; j++)   // wrong!
```

should be

```
for (int j  = 0; j < NumofImages; j++)
```

Comment: Thanks! But Now I get a Null Reference Error at " ListArray[j]++; ". Any Help?

Comment: where/on what line do get the exception?

Comment: " ListArray[j]++; " in ChangeImage()

Comment: so have you initialised the array `ListArray = new uint[100]`?

Comment: Yup, sorry the error came from my faulty programming, thanks for the answer. :)